# Passing URL in parameters MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a site that collects URLs. A full HTTP URL is entered into a textbox. I am getting a 400 error when a URL is being passed in the parameter. It works fine with regular text.

Using jQuery, how can I pass the full URL in my application?

**MVC Routing Config:**

```
 routes.MapRoute("UploadLinks", "media/upload_links/{link}/{albumID}",
                       new { controller = "Media", action = "WebLinkUpload" });
```

**Controller Action:**

```
 public ActionResult WebLinkUpload(string link, string albumID){}
```

**jQuery AJAX call:**

```
$('#btnUploadWebUpload').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/media/upload_links/" + encodeURIComponent($('#txtWebUrl').val().trim()) + "/" + currentAlbumID,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain characters are not allowed in the path portion of the url. Here's a [nice article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) in which Scott Hanselman gives more details. I would recommend you passing the `link` as query string parameter and not as part of the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UploadLinks", 
    "media/upload_links/{albumID}",
    new { controller = "Media", action = "WebLinkUpload" }
);
```

and then:

```
$('#btnUploadWebUpload').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/media/upload_links/' + currentAlbumID,
        data: { link: $('#txtWebUrl').val().trim() },
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
});
```

Also notice that I have removed the `contentType: 'application/json'` from the AJAX call which is wrong. You are not sending any JSON request. It's a GET request.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` must be used to encode query string parameter values, not portions of the path. So no, he didn't encode it. No matter how you encode it the web server won't allow you some special characters in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your map route call comes before the default.  If it doesn't, it would try calling a media controller with a upload_links action.